java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid API Key
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid API Key
    at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.InternalAuthManager.<init>(InternalAuthManager.java:59)
    at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.InternalAuthManager.getInstance(InternalAuthManager.java:48)
    at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.api.authorization.AuthorizationManager.getToken(AuthorizationManager.java:272)
    at com.game.LoginWithAmazonActivity.onStart(LoginWithAmazonActivity.java:105)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2983)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6775)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)



I use the test package is normal, can pull up Amazon login, but the official package with Public Key, and then api_key.txt also changed or not, anyone know what is going on?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
